# Lyapunov Exponent

Tags: differential-equations, code-request

Does anyone know a (simple) Mathematica code for computing the [Lyuponov Exponent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent) for the Rossler System?

Thank you

Rossler System:

```
rossler = {

 x'[t] == -(y[t] + z[t]),

 y'[t] == x[t] + 0.1 y[t],

 z'[t] == 0.2 + x[t] z[t] - 5.7 z[t],

 x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1, z[0] == 1

}
```

Comment: user5267, please read this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Thank you for your help. But I really do not know what to do with this link. Can you please explain more about it?

Comment: It is a guide to properly formatting your posts here on StackExchange.  Well formatted questions consistently get more attention and better answers, as well as reduce the burden on those who try to clean up poorly formatting posts.  There is also a "tool bar" above each edit box with a series of icons that can be used for formatting (for example, select your code and click the `{ }` icon).

Comment: Oh. Thanks. It would be helpful.

Answer (score 29):

You can use the LCE package by [Dr Sandri Marco](http://www.msandri.it/soft.html). It is updated for version 7 and I just tried in on your system for V9 and it worked.

Download `lcm.zip` and use the package as instructed

Here is the result of running your system on it on my PC

```
<< lce.m

?LCEsC
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

These are the 3 Lyapunov Exponents for the Rossler system:

```
rossler[{x_, y_, z_}] := {-y - z, x +0.1 y, 0.2 + z (x - 5.7)};
x0 = {1,1,1};
T = 0.2; K = 2000; TR = 1;  stepsize = 0.001;
lcesrossler = LCEsC[rossler, x0, T, K, TR, stepsize ]
LyapunovDimension[First[lcesrossler]]
T = 100; TR = 20;
PhaseSpaceC[rossler, x0, T, TR, stepsize, {1, 2, 3}]
```

giving:

```
{0.0647984, 0.00535441, -5.23912}
```

These are close to the known values for this system as given at [Prof Sprott](http://sprott.physics.wisc.edu/chaos/comchaos.htm) site where he has done research in this. From the above page:

```
Lyapunov exponents (base-e): = 0.0714, 0, -5.3943
```

By changing the computation parameters and if you have more time to wait, the result can be improved more to become closer to the known values.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It was awesome. Thanks man :)

Comment: Yes, this package is golden! Its awesome.

Comment: How to use this package when ths sistem is driven. I mean the system have a equation like this `x'[t]==-(y[t]+z[t])+Exp[I*t]`. Can I use this package directly?

Answer (score 28):

*Update May 3, 2022:* Added `c, i, j` as local variables

*Update Mar 12, 2022:* Fixed mistake in implementation of `PlotExponents`

*Update Apr 27, 2020:* Got rid of `AppendTo` and added `PlotExponents` and `PlotOpts` options.

*Update Nov 6, 2018:* Tweaked to work on nonautonomous systems, to fix problem reported [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/185364/6358).

Here's an updated implementation (works with MMA v11) that generalizes [Housam Binous & Nasri Zakia's update](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7109/) to [Marco Sandri's package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/2902/) and incorporates [ideas from @bbgodfrey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151234/6358).  The main advantage is that it uses `NDSolve` rather than Euler's method for solving the differential equations, so it should be more accurate / faster than Sandri's implementation.

First, define [@halirutan's GramSchmidt](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37357/6358):

```
GramSchmidt[w_?MatrixQ] := Module[{v = ConstantArray[0, Length[w]]}, 
  Table[v[[n]] = w[[n]] - Sum[(v[[i]].w[[n]]/v[[i]].v[[i]])*v[[i]], {i, n - 1}], {n, Length[w]}];
  v]
```

Then the main function:

```
LyapunovExponents[eqnsin_List, icsin : ({__Rule} | _Association), nlein_Integer: 0, opts___?OptionQ] := Module[{

(* options *)
tstep, maxsteps, ndsolveopts, logbase, showplot, plotexponents, plotopts,

(* iterators *)
c, i, j,

(* other variables *)
δ, neq, nle, vars, rhs, jac, eqns, unks, ics, cum, res, edat, state, newstate, sol, W, norms},
   
(* parse options *)
tstep = Evaluate[TStep /. Flatten[{opts, Options[LyapunovExponents]}]];
maxsteps = Evaluate[MaxSteps /. Flatten[{opts, Options[LyapunovExponents]}]];
ndsolveopts = Evaluate[NDSolveOpts /. Flatten[{opts, Options[LyapunovExponents]}]];
logbase =Evaluate[LogBase /. Flatten[{opts, Options[LyapunovExponents]}]];
showplot = Evaluate[ShowPlot /. Flatten[{opts, Options[LyapunovExponents]}]];
plotexponents = Evaluate[PlotExponents /. Flatten[{opts, Options[LyapunovExponents]}]];
plotopts = Evaluate[PlotOpts /. Flatten[{opts, Options[LyapunovExponents]}]];
  
neq = Length[eqnsin];
If[nlein == 0, nle = neq, nle = nlein]; (* how many exponents *)
   
(* extract vars and right hand sides from eqnsin *)
vars = eqnsin[[All, 1, 0, 1]];
rhs = eqnsin[[All, 2]];
   
(* jacobian matrix *)
jac = D[rhs, {Replace[vars, {x_ -> x[t]}, 1]}];
   
eqns = Join[
  eqnsin,
  Flatten[Table[δ[i, j]'[t] == (jac.Table[δ[i, j][t], {i, neq}])[[i]], {j, nle}, {i, neq}]]
];
unks = Join[
  vars,
  Flatten[Table[δ[i, j], {j, nle}, {i, neq}]]
];
ics = Join[
  Table[var[0] == (var /. icsin), {var, vars}],
  Flatten[Table[δ[i, j][0] == IdentityMatrix[neq][[i, j]], {j, nle}, {i, neq}]]
];

cum = Table[0, {nle}];

state = First@NDSolve`ProcessEquations[Flatten[Join[eqns, ics]], unks, t, Evaluate[Sequence @@ ndsolveopts]];

(* main loop *) 

edat = Table[
  newstate = First@NDSolve`Reinitialize[state, ics];
  NDSolve`Iterate[newstate, c tstep];
  sol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[newstate];

  W = GramSchmidt[Evaluate[Table[δ[i, j][c tstep], {j, nle}, {i, neq}] /. sol]];
  norms = Map[Norm, W];

  (* update running vector magnitudes *)
  cum = cum + Log[logbase, norms];

  ics = Join[
    Table[var[c tstep] == (var[c tstep] /. sol), {var, vars}],
    Flatten[Table[δ[i, j][c tstep] == (W/norms)[[j, i]], {j, nle}, {i, neq}]]
  ];
  cum/(c tstep)
, {c, maxsteps}];
   
If[showplot, Print[ListPlot[Transpose[edat][[1 ;; plotexponents]], Evaluate[Sequence @@ plotopts]]]];
   
Return[cum/(maxsteps tstep)]
];

Options[LyapunovExponents] = {NDSolveOpts -> {}, TStep -> 1, MaxSteps -> 10^4, LogBase -> E,
  ShowPlot -> False, PlotExponents -> 1, PlotOpts -> {}};
```

Now, onto the Rössler system.  Note, the constant 0.1 in OP's equations should be 0.2 to match [Sprott's results](http://sprott.physics.wisc.edu/chaos/comchaos.htm) (otherwise the system is not chaotic).  Let's look at the attractor.

```
eqns = {x'[t] == -(y[t] + z[t]), y'[t] == x[t] + 0.2 y[t],
  z'[t] == 0.2 + z[t] (x[t] - 5.7)};
sol = NDSolve[{eqns, {x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1, z[0] == 1}}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 1000}][[1]];
ParametricPlot3D[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol, {t, 900, 1000},  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, use the final values to start `LyapunovExponents`.

```
ics = {x -> 0.785, y -> -4.34, z -> 0.036};
LyapunovExponents[eqns, ics, ShowPlot -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(* {0.0710707, 0.000384542, -5.39372} *)
```

Pretty close to Sprott's values of `{0.0714, 0, -5.3943}` as referenced by @Nasser.  If we want more accuracy, just increase `MaxSteps`.

```
LyapunovExponents[eqns, ics, ShowPlot -> True, MaxSteps -> 10^5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(* {0.071127, 0.0000389742, -5.39419} *)
```

**References:**

Sandri M (1996) Numerical calculation of Lyapunov exponents. The Mathematica Journal 6:78–84. https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/2902/

Wolf A, Swift JB, Swinney HL, Vastano JA (1985) Determining Lyapunov exponents from a time series. Physica D: Nonlinear Phenomena 16:285–317. https://doi.org/10.1016/0167-2789(85)90011-9

Comment: I copied your code into Mathematica 11, but it tells me that parts of $\delta$ are undefined. I indeed see the 'other variable' $\delta$ in the function LyapunovExponents not being specified somewhere. Is it possible you forgot a line? The output of the LyapunovExponents function fails for me because it tries to evaluate Log[GramSchmidt[Norm[...]]] where the dots are the undefined components of $\delta$.

Comment: @JgL Ugh, a semicolon was missing at the end of the line that starts `jac =`.  Could you give it a try now?  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! It runs perfectly now

Comment: Note: That `GramSchmidt` does not provide an ortho*normal* basis of the span of the given list of vectors, just an orthogonal basis. (The built-in function `Orthogonalize` does provide an orthonormal basis -- despite its misleading name!)

Comment: @murray Thanks for the info, but I'm not sure I can use `Orthogonalize` here, since we need the value of the `norms` in addition to the orthonormal basis. Let me know if you have thoughts.

Comment: Is it possible to do this process in reverse, where I use a set of Lyapunov exponents to determine the orbits of the Rössler system? If so, could how would I go about plotting them? EG. Known [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/futsK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/futsK.png) Unknown [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzYbl.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzYbl.png)

Comment: I copied your code as a package and tried to run it but it just keeps showing an error when I try to call the package using Get from the Notebook. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: @d_g I don't know about the package approach.  You could just copy the definition into a cell in your notebook -- does that work?

Comment: @ChrisK yes that works, thank you so much! Also if I dont first use NDSolve and directly use the LyapunovExponents function, there shouldnt be any problem right?

Comment: @d_g Should be OK!

Comment: Thanks a lot @ChrisK! This code is extremely helpful.

Comment: If I had a system like a bouncing ball where I need NDSolve to handle collisions, how would I add this detail to your Lyapunov code above?

Comment: @BoJohnson Sorry, I haven't studied how to calculate Lyapunov exponents in systems with events.  Do you have any mathematical references?  In any case, you could start a new question here.

Comment: @ChrisK I don't know if what I'm looking for is anything theoretically different in the calculation of the Lyapunov spectrum from what you have above. I'm just more wondering if I can pass something like WhenEvent to NDSolve in the code above.

Comment: @ChrisK The `nlein_Integer: 0` in the function 'LyapunovExponents[]' can only be taken as '0', and it doesn't work if it is set to be other numbers(100 or 1000), can you fix it?

Comment: @keanhy14 `nlein` is the number of Lyapunov exponents to be calculated.  It should be an integer <= the dimension of the system.  The default (0) gives all of them.  Unless you have a 100- or 1000-dimensional system, setting it so high won't work.

Comment: @ChrisK Your code works well, and I think it will be better if you exclude the transient  `TR` steps, just as illustrated in `Marco Sandri's package`, especially for the damping system.

Comment: @keanhy14 Thanks!  Just warm the system up with `NDSolve` to get on the attractor before calling `LyapunovExponents`.

Comment: how did you get the values of ics (x,y,z)?

Comment: On 13.0.1 and after all fixes MaxSteps -> 10^5 now works much better than you described (vs Sprott). It gives 0.0713009, 0.00003218, -5.39445.

Comment: @ChrisK, thank you for writing such a beautiful program. Could you give me a hint how to find Lyapunov spectrum for Billiards? I'm unable to find an algorithm based on this slide https://www.uv.mx/ffia/files/2021/03/Chaotic-Classical-Billiards.pdf

Comment: @user444 Sorry, I have no idea. If you can define the problem in terms of a system of differential equations, you can use my `LyapunovExponents` function, but I'm afraid the discrete collisions will cause problems. You should ask a new question to get more eyeballs on the problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 11):

Here is a sample code on how to compute the evolution of the Lyapunov Characteristic Exopnent (LCE) with Mathematica. Feel free to make any changes you like and let me know if this is what you wanted.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
deq1 = -(y1[t] + z1[t]);
deq2 = x1[t] + 0.1 y1[t];
deq3 = 0.2 + x1[t] z1[t] - 5.7 z1[t];

deq4 = -(y2[t] + z2[t]);
deq5 = x2[t] + 0.1 y2[t];
deq6 = 0.2 + x2[t] z2[t] - 5.7 z2[t];

x10 = 1; y10 = 1; z10 = 1;
dx0 = 10^-8;
x20 = x10 + dx0; y20 = y10; z20 = z10;
tin = 0; tfin = 10000;
tstep = 1;
acc = 12;

lcedata = {};
sum = 0;

d0 = Sqrt[(x10 - x20)^2 + (y10 - y20)^2 + (z10 - z20)^2 ];

For[i = 1, i < tfin/tstep, i++,

sdeq = {x1'[t] == deq1, y1'[t] == deq2, z1'[t] == deq3, 
x2'[t] == deq4, y2'[t] == deq5, z2'[t] == deq6, x1[0] == x10, 
y1[0] == y10, z1[0] == z10, x2[0] == x20, y2[0] == y20, 
z2[0] == z20};
sol = NDSolve[
sdeq, {x1[t], y1[t], z1[t], x2[t], y2[t], z2[t]}, {t, 0, tstep}, 
MaxSteps -> Infinity, Method -> "Adams", PrecisionGoal -> acc, 
AccuracyGoal -> acc];

xx1[t_]  = x1[t] /. sol[[1]];
yy1[t_]  = y1[t] /. sol[[1]];
zz1[t_] = z1[t] /. sol[[1]];

xx2[t_]  = x2[t] /. sol[[1]];
yy2[t_]  = y2[t] /. sol[[1]];
zz2[t_] = z2[t] /. sol[[1]];

d1 = Sqrt[(xx1[tstep] - xx2[tstep])^2 + (yy1[tstep] - yy2[tstep])^2 + 
          (zz1[tstep] - zz2[tstep])^2 ];

sum += Log[d1/d0];
dlce = sum/(tstep*i);
AppendTo[lcedata, {tstep*i, Log10[dlce]}];

w1 = (xx1[tstep] - xx2[tstep])*(d0/d1); 
w2 = (yy1[tstep] - yy2[tstep])*(d0/d1);
w3 = (zz1[tstep] - zz2[tstep])*(d0/d1); 

x10 = xx1[tstep];
y10 = yy1[tstep];
z10 = zz1[tstep];

x20 = x10 + w1;
y20 = y10 + w2;
z20 = z10 + w3;

i = i++;

If[Mod[tstep*i, 100] == 0, 
Print[" For t = ", tstep*i, " , ", " LCE = ", dlce]]

]

S0 = ListPlot[{lcedata}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
          FrameLabel -> {"t", "log10(LCE)"}, 
FrameStyle -> Directive["Helvetica", 17], ImageSize -> 550]
```

Comment: thank you so much. It was really great and helpful.

Comment: May I ask a question? What the difference between the  Lyapunov Characteristic Exopnent in this progress and the Maximal Lyapunov exponent?

Answer (score 9):

At first, let's solve the system of ODEs. Taking into account that you give specific initial conditions, then the solution of the system will correspond to a three-dimensional orbit. The following code solves the system of the ODEs and also plots the output 3D orbit. Now, about the Lyapunov Exponent. How exactly do you define this exponent. I mean, by using the variational equations or by monitoring the deviation between two initially nearby orbits? If it is the latter, then I could provide such a Mathematica code.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
deq1 = -(y[t] + z[t]);
deq2 = x[t] + 0.1 y[t];
deq3 = 0.2 + x[t] z[t] - 5.7 z[t];
x0 = y0 = z0 = 1;
tin = 0;
tfin = 50;
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == deq1, y'[t] == deq2, z'[t] == deq3, 
x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, z[0] == z0}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, tin, 
tfin}];
xt = x[t] /. sol[[1]];
yt = y[t] /. sol[[1]];
zt = z[t] /. sol[[1]];
P1 = ParametricPlot3D[{xt, yt, zt}, {t, tin, tfin}, 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.By the way, I think that these two methods almost give the same results. Aren't they?! I appreciate it, if you share your idea about it.

Comment: Can you help me in computing the largest Lyapunov exponent in the case of variational equations...do we have to do analytically or computationally, please suggest some methods to compute this lyapunov exponent!.