# Orthogonalizing without normalizing

Tags: functions, vector

Is there a way to make `Orthogonalize` do the normal Gram-Schmidt procedure without normalizing the result? As far as I've understood this was possible with Mathematica 5.2.

One way would be to just multiply with the norms but being complicated expressions the whole thing would be easier without normalizing in the first place.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about writing the Gram-Schmit down by yourself?

```
GramSchmidt[w_?MatrixQ] := Module[{v = ConstantArray[0, Length[w]]},
  Table[
    v[[n]] = w[[n]] - 
      Sum[(v[[i]].w[[n]]/v[[i]].v[[i]])*v[[i]], {i, 1, n - 1}], 
    {n, 1, Length[w]}];
  v
]
```

Then you have the unscaled orthogonal basis

```
GramSchmidt[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1/2, 1/3}, {1, 2, 3}}]
Graphics3D[Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, #}] & /@ %]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! That's great. I actually need it for a nonstandard inner product but probably that can be easily incorporated into your function.

Comment: @halirutan, you could generalize this to linearly dependent set of vectors by adding a condition. Right now, it returns Indeterminate on for example, w = {{4, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 3}};

Comment: @cleanplay The question is, what result do you expect? The original `Orthogonalize` gives you a null-vector if it is dependent on some former vector. In numerical applications, one maybe likes a different approach. You could for instance make a small random perturbation and get a normal basis even with dependent vectors.

Comment: @halirutan I have copied your code, it is showing `SyntaxError: Incomplete Expression; More input needed` when I am using it with some code you can see [here](https://imgur.com/a/WJgIDgn). Can we use capital letter for functions not defined in Mathematica? Please help..

Comment: @taritgoswami post a question and also with copyable code, pictures are useless for us to help :)