# Orthogonalizing without normalizing part 2

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics

After some searching I couldn't find an existing solution that lets you compute orthogonal (not orthonormal basis) without computing huge performance penalty relative to `Orthogonalize`. Any suggestions how to speed it up?

Two versions below compute desired quantity, but 30x slower than built-in Orthogonalize. It doesn't seem to [be possible](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-orthogonalize-bug.nb) to use `Orthogonalize` with custom dot product function to achieve this (suggested in earlier [version](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37354/orthogonalizing-without-normalizing))

```
d = 200;
numSamples = d;
sigma = DiagonalMatrix[Table[1., {i, 1, d}]];
dist = MultinormalDistribution[sigma];
data = RandomVariate[dist, numSamples];
data = Normalize /@ data;

(* Version from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37357/217 *)
GramSchmidt[w_?MatrixQ] := Module[{v = ConstantArray[0, Length[w]]},
   Table[
    v[[n]] = 
     w[[n]] - 
      Sum[(v[[i]] . w[[n]]/v[[i]] . v[[i]])*v[[i]], {i, 1, 
        n - 1}], {n, 1, Length[w]}];
   v];


(* modified version from \
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101463/217 *)
proj[u_, v_] := v . u/u . u u;
gsOrthogonal[vectorSet_?MatrixQ] := 
  Map[With[{norm = Norm[#]}, If[norm > 0, #, #]] &, 
   Fold[Function[{spanVec, v}, 
       Join[spanVec, {v - 
          Total@Map[proj[#, v] &, 
            spanVec]}]][#1, #2] &, {vectorSet[[1]]}, 
    Drop[vectorSet, 1]]];


Print["Built-in timing: ", First@Timing@Orthogonalize[data]]
Print["version1 timing: ", First@Timing@GramSchmidt@data]
Print["version2 timing: ", First@Timing@gsOrthogonal@data]
```

Produces

```
Built-in timing: 0.021098

version1 timing: 0.829932

version2 timing: 0.629197
```

Comment: Version 13.1: Help for "Orthogonalize": Orthogonalize[{Subscript[e, 1],Subscript[e, 2],\[Ellipsis]},f]  gives an orthonormal basis found by orthogonalizing the elements Subscript[e, i] with respect to the inner product function f.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can use a QR decomposition:

```
GramSchmidt[M_] := With[{qr=QRDecomposition[Transpose[M]]},
                     Diagonal[Last[qr]]*First[qr]];
```

Comment: Thanks, that [turns out](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-orthogonalize-bug.nb) to be 5x faster than `Orthogonalize`