# Find an orthonormal basis for column space without Orthogonalize

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

How can I find an orthonormal basis for column space of the following matrix without using `Orthogonalize`?

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
-10 & 13 & 7 & -11 \\
2 & 1 & -5 & 3 \\
-6 & 3 & 13 & -3 \\
16 & -16 & -2 & 5 \\
2 & 1 & -5 & -7 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: *Supposed to say “Use list command. Cannot use orthogonalize command”

Comment: Hi. Could you please give code of your own attempts at tackling this problem?

Comment: This is an 5x4 matrix. a map from a  C^4 to another C

Comment: Just use `Transpose@GramSchmidt@Transpose@m` - you can get `GramSchmidt` from [halirutan's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37357/72682) - the columns of the resulting matrix will be orthonormal - remove the first transpose to get the basis as mathematica 'vectors'

Comment: No, I need it in orthonormal form, I’m just not sure how to get that without using the orthogonalize command.

Comment: What have you tried?  And just wondering:  Why is `Orthogonalize` forbidden here?

Comment: You can adapt that answer and do the normalize yourself using `Normalize`. That's really not difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
UpperTriangularize[m]
```

as a first step.

Answer (score -1):

```
m = {{-10, 13, 7, -11},
   {2, 1, -5, 3 },
   {-6, 3, 13, -3 },
   {16, -16, -2, 5 },
   {2, 1, -5, -7}}

Orthogonalize[m\[Transpose]]*{10, 2, Sqrt[3], Sqrt[2]}

{{-5, 1, -3, 8, 1}, {1, 1, -1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, -1}}
```

In order to adapt the basis to the  Nullspace and its orthogonal complement:  there is a 1d nullspace

```
x0= NullSpace[m\[Transpose]][[1]]

x0 . m
{0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Next, take a unit vector and subtract it's projection to x0

```
x1 = (#2-#1 * #1 . #2 / Norm[#1]^2 &)[x0, UnitVector[5, 2]]

{1/5, 19/25, -(7/25), 2/25, -(6/25)}

x1.x0
0
```

for the following vectors taken from the Set of UnitVector list, you have to subtact the sum of the projections to the foregoing.

Write a Do loop or a FoldList procedure running over the UnitVector List. Divide each vector by its norm, if an orthonormal system is sought.