# Lyapunov Exponent of Mackey Glass Equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

In order to find out the Lyapunov Exponent of Mackey Glass Equation I have used the following program.

```
g[x_, t_, τ_] := (1/4) x[t - τ]/(1 + x[t - τ]^10) - x[t]/10;
lyapunov[f_, x0_, τ_, t_, n_, tr_: 0] := 
  Module[{df, xi}, df = Derivative[1, 0][f]; xi = NestList[f[#, τ] &, x0, n - 1];
    (1/n) Total[Log[Abs[df[#, τ]]] & /@ Drop[xi, tr]]];
gtable = Table[{τ, 
    lyapunov[g, 0.5, τ, 10000, 5000]}, {τ, 14, 40, 0.01}, {t, 17, 4000, 17}];
ListPlot[#, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> τ", "λ"}, Joined -> True] & /@ {gtable}
```

This program I got from [Lyapunov exponent plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81230/lyapunov-exponent-plot). I have only modified it for Mackey Glass equation which is `x'[t] == (1/4) x[t - τ]/ (1 + x[t - τ]^10) - x[t]/10`; Unfortunately it is taking a long time and I am not getting any result. Please help me to find out the mistake.

Comment: Your `g` is a function of 3 arguments. You pass it as a first argument in `lyapunov`, where it's called `f_`; then you have `NestList[f[#, \[Tau]] &`, where `f` is a function of 2 arguments. So basically you wrote a program for 2-argument functions and want it to work on 3-argument ones.

Comment: So how I can write f as a function of 3 arguments?

Comment: `lyapunov` in the original post calculates Lyapunov exponent of **function**, while you're trying to calculate "Lyapunov Exponent of delayed differential equation". What's "Lyapunov Exponent of delayed differential equation"? If you want to find Lyapunov Exponent of `x[t]` in the equation, then you need to solve the equation first, but it's another story.