# How to use Lyapunov Exponent to evaluate the performance of a chaotic map

Tags: differential-equations, code-request

Any simple Mathematica code for Lyapunov exponent. Considering the figure below which is a chaotic map using Sine Map, Tent Map and Henon Map [image]. How to use Lyapunov Exponent to evaluate the performance of this chaotic map. The equations are as follows [image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DAJ1.jpg).
The STH (Sine Map, Tent Map and Henon Map) that I did is as

```
sth0 = 0.929688; 
sth1 = 0.488281; 
r = 0.5; 
u = RandomReal[{0.87, 1}]; 
β = RandomReal[{0, 1}]; 
x0 = RandomReal[{0, 1}]; 
sth[0] = Abs[u - 10*Sin[Pi*sth1]^2 + β*r*Abs[1 - 2*sth0]];

sth[m_] := sth[m] = Abs[u - 10*Sin[Pi*sth[m - 1]]^2 + 
  β*r*Abs[1 - 2*sth[m - 1]]]; 
Table[sth[m], {m, 0, Ceiling[512*512*(3/4)]}];
```

I need to plot the Lyapunov exponent for this STH to evaluate its performance.
I found similar problems [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81230/discrete-time-lyapunov-exponent-plot?noredirect=1&lq=1)  and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17593/lyapunov-exponent) but can't apply them to my solution.

Comment: Can you clarify $HM$; is $STH(n+1)=HM(n+1)=1-ur\cdot\sin^2(\pi STH(n))+\beta r\cdot|(1-2STH(n-1)|$?  Also, are you interested in computing $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\ln|STH'(x_i)|$ for many $x_0$'s (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent)?  Is numerical approximation OK?

Comment: Look at the code from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81230/discrete-time-lyapunov-exponent-plot.  How do you compute Lyapunov exponents for double recurrences (i.e. $f'(x_i,x_{i-1})$)?  Do you want a plot with $u$ varying or $r$ varying or $\beta$ varying?  For what fixed $x_0$ starting point?  Once these details are hashed out, the code can be adapted.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it.  And they like it to appear in the question instead of the comments. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: @Adam I have modified in the post