# Lyapunov exponent of a Henon map?

Tags: code-request

Can anyone help me with calculating Lyapunov exponent of 2D map, for example Henon map? 
If there is simple code, that would be great!

Comment: Can you explain what it is or provide a link...?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HenonMap.html may be of help

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Search Google for "Lyapunov exponent Mathematica" to find many references.  [This one](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7109/).is a possibility.

Comment: Consider also [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEgQFjAFahUKEwjww8CowqfIAhUCzIAKHeYPCKk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zju.edu.cn%2Fjzus%2Fopentxt.php%3Fdoi%3D10.1631%2Fjzus.2005.A0296&usg=AFQjCNFdLWY8fxrSfyl4ohqsOgEMvSYk4A&sig2=z_i8KJiOxdDe551F3EKY_Q).

Answer (score 5):

As noted in [Nasser's answer to 17593](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17608/1063), code to solve this problem already exists and can be downloaded from the web site of [Dr Marco Sandri](http://www.msandri.it/soft.html), who also wrote an [article](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v6i3/article/sandri/contents/63sandri.pdf) explaining his algorithms.  Once downloaded, `lce.m` should be stored in some accessible place on the disk, for instance, the subdirectory `MyPackages` of `Mathematica`.  The calculation proceeds as follows.

```
AppendTo[$Path, FileNameJoin[{$UserDocumentsDirectory, "Mathematica/MyPackages"}]]; 
Quiet@Needs["lce`"]
```

Then, define the Henon recurrence function.

```
α = 1.4; β = .3;
h[{x_, y_}] := {1 - α x^2 + y, β x}
```

If desired, the Henon Map can be plotted.

```
lst = NestList[h, {.1, 0}, 40000];
ListPlot[lst, PlotStyle -> Red, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]

As noted in a comment above by [thils](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/6318/thils), further discussion of the Henon Map is at [Wolfram  MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HenonMap.html).  The Lyapunov exponent now can be found with

```
LCEsD[h, {0.1, 0}, 1000, 100, LCEsPlot -> False]
(* {{0.445647, -1.64962}, 1.27015} *)
```

the first two numbers being numerical estimates of the exponents, and the third the approximate dimension of the attractor.  The convergence rate of the approximation can be obtained, if desired, from

```
LCEsD[h, {0.1, 0}, 1000, 100, LCEsPlot -> True]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

Lyapunov exponents for a range of parameters can be computed quickly, for instance,

```
ly = Quiet@Table[h[{x_, y_}] := {1 - α x^2 + y, β x}; 
    {α, LCEsD[h, {0.1, 0}, 1000, 100, LCEsPlot -> False][[1, 1]]}, {α, 1.0, 1.4, 0.005}]
ListPlot[ly, AxesLabel -> {"α", None}]
```

[image]

Negative exponents correspond to stable windows within an otherwise chaotic band. (`LCEsD` is unable to compute the dimension of the attractor, which is zero in these cases, and instead generates a number of error messages.  `Quiet` is used to suppress them.)  As an example, the Henon Map for `α = 1.23` is finite number of discrete points, representing a normal, although complicated, attractor.  (`PointSize[.01]` is used in this plot to improve visibility of the points.)

[image]

Comment: This is what I want to do @bbgodfrey. Great Job !

Answer (score 0):

This [paper](https://www.aip.org/cip/pdf/vol_12/iss_6/608_1.pdf) provides a reasonable background to evaluation of the Lyaponov exponent. Description of the Henon map is also provided. For the case of the Henon map, we include two parameters `(α, β`), and we can start by using

```
n = 100; 
max = 20; 
r = 0.005;

 Manipulate[
 ListPlot[Flatten[
   Table[({α, #1} & ) /@ 
     Take[Quiet[
       NestList[{#1[[2]] + 
            1 - α*#1[[1]]^2, β*#1[[1]]} & , {-0.1, 0.}, 
         n][[All, 1]]], -max], {α, 0.9, 1.5, r}], 1]], 
    {β, 0.1, 0.25}]
```

`n` is the no. of iterations, `r` is resolution of the parameter `α` and `max` is the maximum period. All these variables determine the computational time.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the OP's question other than by providing an link to another site. The OP didn't ask for code that draws the bifurcation diagram.

Comment: @m_Goldberg I ran out time, hopefully will attach the 2nd part which shows explicit calc of lyapunov exponent which can compare with the Ice.m package (@bbgodfrey response).