# Lyapunov Exponent from time series data for delay differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

If I have 2000 data points for the following equation ,How to find out the Lyapunov exponent for different values of [Tau] .This is a delay differential equation i.e infinite dimensional system.

```
b = 1;
V0 = 300;
I0 = 0.001;
N1 = 7/4;
p1 = (\[Pi]*b*N1)/V0;
a1 = 1.001; a2 = 0.123; a3 = -3.622*10^-3; b1 = 0.001959; b2 = 0.031; 
b3 = 0.003241; G = 0.5*10^-5; \[CapitalOmega] = 0; C1 = p1/2000;
f = 1*10^3;
Is = 0.0;
\[Tau] = 15;
NL = 1000;

sol1[t_] = 
 NDSolve[{x'[t] - (I0*p1)/(
      2*C1)*((a1*x[t - \[Tau]] - G/(p1*I0)*x[t]) - 
        3/4*x[t - \[Tau]]^3*a2 - 5/8*a3*x[t - \[Tau]]^5) - 
     Is*p1*Cos[y[t]] == 0, 
   y'[t] - \[CapitalOmega] - (I0*p1)/(
      2*C1*x[t])*(b1*x[t - \[Tau]] + 3/4*x[t - \[Tau]]^3*b2 - 
        5/8*b3*x[t - \[Tau]]^5) + (Is*p1)/(2*C1*x[t])*Sin[y[t]] == 0, 
   x[0] == 0.003, y[0] == 0.001}, {x, y}, {t, 0, NL}]
```

Comment: Not implemented in MMA except for [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20100821131053/http://www.internationalmathematicasymposium.org/IMS99/paper25/ims99paper25.nb), which is pre-MMA8 and I didn't make it work. Try using other implementations, e.g. [TISEAN](http://www.mpipks-dresden.mpg.de/~tisean/), [.exe programmes](http://www.matjazperc.com/ejp/time.html) or [Wolf et. al fortran implementation](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0167278985900119).

Comment: So there is no way to find out Lyapunov Exponent of DDE using Mathematica?

Comment: There could be different approaches depending on whether you want a method to work on a time series (see @corey979's response and [this yet-unanswered question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25984/how-can-i-calculate-the-correlation-dimension-and-or-the-lyapunov-exponent-of-a)) or a method to work inside the `NDSolve` (see [Marco Sandri's package](http://www.msandri.it/soft.html), but it's not clear it it will work on a delay equation without modification).  Judging from the multiple unanswered questions on this topic, looks like something a lot of people want.

Comment: In another post  ( http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125613/lyapunov-exponent-of-delay-differential-equation ) I have given a program where I have tried to find out LE using NDSolve but the problem of that code is for different values of \[Tau] I am getting the same result which is not correct. Can I get help to modify that code so that I can get different LE for different \[Tau] .

Comment: What definition of Lyapunov Exponent are you using for the delay differential equation?

Comment: Please visit this https://cds.cern.ch/record/1338608/files/978-3-642-14938-2_BookBackMatter.pdf