# Lyapunov Exponent of the Rössler System

Tags: plotting, graphics

I would like to plot a semi-log plot of the Lyapunov exponent $λ_{x_0}, x_0=(1,1,1) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ versus time $t$, for the Rössler system described by:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{lcl}\dot{x}& =& -y-z \\ \dot{y} &=&x+ay \\ \dot{z}&=& b+z(x-c) \end{array}
\end{equation}
where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ real parameters of the system.

Now, the attractor is usually met for $a=b=0.2$ and $c=5.7$. My target is to show that the plot which is derived by plotting the log of the distance between trajectories is well approximated by a straight line with a positive slope *(which is actually the Lyapunov exponent)*, so the Rössler system has a positive Lyapunov exponent and experiences chaotic motion.

What I have managed so far by searching in stack.exchange is to find something similar on [Lyapunov Exponent for Rössler System](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17593/lyapunov-exponent) which is provided as:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
deq1 = -(y1[t] + z1[t]);
deq2 = x1[t] + 0.1 y1[t];
deq3 = 0.2 + x1[t] z1[t] - 5.7 z1[t];

deq4 = -(y2[t] + z2[t]);
deq5 = x2[t] + 0.1 y2[t];
deq6 = 0.2 + x2[t] z2[t] - 5.7 z2[t];

x10 = 1; y10 = 1; z10 = 1;
dx0 = 10^-8;
x20 = x10 + dx0; y20 = y10; z20 = z10;
tin = 0; tfin = 10000;
tstep = 1;
acc = 12;

lcedata = {};
sum = 0;

d0 = Sqrt[(x10 - x20)^2 + (y10 - y20)^2 + (z10 - z20)^2 ];

For[i = 1, i < tfin/tstep, i++,

sdeq = {x1'[t] == deq1, y1'[t] == deq2, z1'[t] == deq3, 
x2'[t] == deq4, y2'[t] == deq5, z2'[t] == deq6, x1[0] == x10, 
y1[0] == y10, z1[0] == z10, x2[0] == x20, y2[0] == y20, 
z2[0] == z20};
sol = NDSolve[
sdeq, {x1[t], y1[t], z1[t], x2[t], y2[t], z2[t]}, {t, 0, tstep}, 
MaxSteps -> Infinity, Method -> "Adams", PrecisionGoal -> acc, 
AccuracyGoal -> acc];

xx1[t_]  = x1[t] /. sol[[1]];
yy1[t_]  = y1[t] /. sol[[1]];
zz1[t_] = z1[t] /. sol[[1]];

xx2[t_]  = x2[t] /. sol[[1]];
yy2[t_]  = y2[t] /. sol[[1]];
zz2[t_] = z2[t] /. sol[[1]];

d1 = Sqrt[(xx1[tstep] - xx2[tstep])^2 + (yy1[tstep] - yy2[tstep])^2 + 
          (zz1[tstep] - zz2[tstep])^2 ];

sum += Log[d1/d0];
dlce = sum/(tstep*i);
AppendTo[lcedata, {tstep*i, Log10[dlce]}];

w1 = (xx1[tstep] - xx2[tstep])*(d0/d1); 
w2 = (yy1[tstep] - yy2[tstep])*(d0/d1);
w3 = (zz1[tstep] - zz2[tstep])*(d0/d1); 

x10 = xx1[tstep];
y10 = yy1[tstep];
z10 = zz1[tstep];

x20 = x10 + w1;
y20 = y10 + w2;
z20 = z10 + w3;

i = i++;

If[Mod[tstep*i, 100] == 0, 
Print[" For t = ", tstep*i, " , ", " LCE = ", dlce]]

]

S0 = ListPlot[{lcedata}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
          FrameLabel -> {"t", "log10(LCE)"}, 
FrameStyle -> Directive["Helvetica", 17], ImageSize -> 550]
```

But what I would like to show is something similar to this analysis [Lyapunov exponent of the Lorenz system](http://www.chebfun.org/examples/ode-nonlin/LyapunovExponents.html).Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: That's quite a bit of code you posted. Could you boil this down to your specific problem? I.e. what does the posted code produce, and what does NOT work in that implementation for you?