# How to access and change the state variable values in NDsolve`Iterate?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

Essentially I am trying to calculate the Lyapunov exponent the naive way; i.e., using the method described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17609/) by Vaggelis_Z.

In each pass of the loop over time a new trajectory is spawned by adding a small displacement vector to the state and running it for a single time step. This is repeated at each time step after renormalisation of the displacement vector.

While invoking the complete NDSolve within the loop works OK, I can see that the costs for a 10+ dimensional system of ODEs will be prohibitive.

I want to speed up things by accessing and changing the state variables and resubmitting them in `` NDSolve`Iterate `` inside the loop. How can I do that?

MarcoB, here's the code I have got

```
 (* original ODE's for the Sprott system *)
 f1 = (y1[t]*z1[t] + 0.01);
 f2 = x1[t]*x1[t] - y1[t];
 f3 = 1 - 4*x1[t] ;
(* cloned ODE's for shadowing the system *)
 f4 = (y2[t]*z2[t] + 0.01);
 f5 = x2[t]*x2[t] - y2[t];
 f6 = 1 - 4*x2[t] ;
 (* starting initial conditions for the original trajectory *)
 x10 = 1; y10 = 1; z10 = 0;
 dx0 = 10^-8;
 (* starting initial conditions for the shadowing trajectory *)
 x20 = x10 + dx0; y20 = y10; z20 = z10;
 tin = 0; tfin = 1000;
 dt = .01;
 iterat = tfin/dt;
 acc = 12;

 lexp = {};
  sum = 0;
 d0 = Sqrt[(x10 - x20)^2 + (y10 - y20)^2 + (z10 - z20)^2];
 Timing[For[i = 1, i < iterat, i++, 
  eqns = {x1'[t] == f1, y1'[t] == f2, z1'[t] == f3, x2'[t] == f4, 
  y2'[t] == f5, z2'[t] == f6, x1[0] == x10, y1[0] == y10, 
  z1[0] == z10, x2[0] == x20, y2[0] == y20, z2[0] == z20};
  sol = NDSolve[
  eqns, {x1[t], y1[t], z1[t], x2[t], y2[t], z2[t]}, {t, 0, dt}, 
  MaxSteps -> Infinity, PrecisionGoal -> acc, AccuracyGoal -> acc];
  (* solution functions  *)
  xx1[t_] = x1[t] /. sol[[1]]; 
  yy1[t_] = y1[t] /. sol[[1]]; 
  zz1[t_] = z1[t] /. sol[[1]]; 
  xx2[t_] = x2[t] /. sol[[1]]; 
  yy2[t_] = y2[t] /. sol[[1]]; 
  zz2[t_] = z2[t] /. sol[[1]]; 
  d1 = Sqrt[(xx1[dt] - xx2[dt])^2 + (yy1[dt] - 
    yy2[dt])^2 + (zz1[dt] - zz2[dt])^2]; 
  sum += Log[d1/d0]; 
  lyap = sum/(dt*i); 
  AppendTo[lexp, {dt*i, Log10[lyap]}]; 
  (* components of  displacement vector normalised to d0 *)
  vc1 = (xx1[dt] - xx2[dt])*(d0/d1); 
  vc2 = (yy1[dt] - yy2[dt])*(d0/d1); 
  vc3 = (zz1[dt] - zz2[dt])*(d0/d1); 
  (*new initial conditions for the original trajectory *)
  x10 = xx1[dt]; 
  y10 = yy1[dt]; 
  z10 = zz1[dt]; 
  (*  new initial conditions spawned for the shadowing trajectory *)
  x20 = x10 + vc1; 
  y20 = y10 + vc2; 
  z20 = z10 + vc3;
   i = i++;
   If[Mod[dt*i, 10] == 0, 
    Print["  t = ", dt*i, " , ", "largest Lyapunov  = ", lyap]]]]
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far?

Comment: the code I was using is basically the one provided by Vaggelis_Z which is quite simple as thats what I have been doing in my Fortran code . however this is slow probably because of carrying the baggage of NDSolve in every pass ?

Comment: MarcoB, size limitations dont dont allow me to post it  here so any suggestions as to how I can put it up for you to have a look ?

Comment: Is your goal to reduce run time or specifically to "change the state variables and resubmit them in NDSolve'Iterate inside the loop"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The run time of the code in the question is 202 seconds on my PC.  Even before employing the component structure of `NDSolve`, it is helpful to eliminate unnecessary code to both increase speed and increase readability.  Doing so yields,

```
f1 = (y1[t]*z1[t] + 0.01);
f2 = x1[t]*x1[t] - y1[t];
f3 = 1 - 4*x1[t] ;
f4 = (y2[t]*z2[t] + 0.01);
f5 = x2[t]*x2[t] - y2[t];
f6 = 1 - 4*x2[t] ;
x10 = 1; y10 = 1; z10 = 0; dx0 = 10^-8;
x20 = x10 + dx0; y20 = y10; z20 = z10;
tin = 0; tfin = 1000; dt = .01; iterat = Round[tfin/dt]; acc = 12;
eqns = {x1'[t] == f1, y1'[t] == f2, z1'[t] == f3, 
        x2'[t] == f4, y2'[t] == f5, z2'[t] == f6};

lexp = ConstantArray[0, iterat - 1]; sum = 0;
d0 = Norm[{x10 , y10, z10} - {x20 , y20, z20}];
Timing[Do [
    ic = {x1[0] == x10, y1[0] == y10, z1[0] == z10, 
          x2[0] == x20, y2[0] == y20, z2[0] == z20};
    sol = Last /@ Flatten@NDSolve[{eqns, ic}, {x1[dt], y1[dt], z1[dt], 
        x2[dt], y2[dt], z2[dt]}, {t, 0, dt}, 
        MaxSteps -> Infinity, PrecisionGoal -> acc, AccuracyGoal -> acc];
    d1 = Norm[sol[[1 ;; 3]] - sol[[4 ;; 6]]]; 
    sum += Log[d1/d0]; 
    lyap = sum/(dt*i); 
    lexp[[i]] = {dt*i, Log10[lyap]}; 
    {x10 , y10, z10} = sol[[1 ;; 3]]; 
    {x20 , y20, z20} = {x10 , y10, z10} + (sol[[1 ;; 3]] - sol[[4 ;; 6]]) (d0/d1); 
    If[Mod[dt*i, 10] == 0, 
    Print["  t = ", dt*i, " , ", "largest Lyapunov  = ", lyap]], {i, iterat - 1}]]
```

The run time now is only 114 seconds.  Although many changes were made, most of the savings were achieved by replacing `AppendTo[lexp, {dt*i, Log10[lyap]}]` by `lexp[[i]] = {dt*i, Log10[lyap]}`.  `AppendTo` is notoriously slow for large arrays, here `100 000` elements.  Asking `NDSolve` to return only the final values, `{x1[dt], y1[dt], z1[dt], x2[dt], y2[dt], z2[dt]}`, instead of `{x1[t], y1[t], z1[t], x2[t], y2[t], z2[t]}` also helps.

Now, employ the `NDSolve` [Component Structure](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html#580655648), which requires only minor modifications to the preceding code.

```
f1 = (y1[t]*z1[t] + 0.01);
f2 = x1[t]*x1[t] - y1[t];
f3 = 1 - 4*x1[t] ;
f4 = (y2[t]*z2[t] + 0.01);
f5 = x2[t]*x2[t] - y2[t];
f6 = 1 - 4*x2[t] ;
x10 = 1; y10 = 1; z10 = 0; dx0 = 10^-8;
x20 = x10 + dx0; y20 = y10; z20 = z10;
tin = 0; tfin = 1000; dt = .01; iterat = Round[tfin/dt]; acc = 12;
eqns = {x1'[t] == f1, y1'[t] == f2, z1'[t] == f3, 
        x2'[t] == f4, y2'[t] == f5, z2'[t] == f6};
ic = {x1[0] == x10, y1[0] == y10, z1[0] == z10, x2[0] == x20, y2[0] == y20, z2[0] == z20};
state = First@NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{eqns, ic}, 
    {x1[dt], y1[dt], z1[dt], x2[dt], y2[dt], z2[dt]}, t , 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity, PrecisionGoal -> acc, AccuracyGoal -> acc];

lexp = ConstantArray[0, iterat - 1]; sum = 0;
d0 = Norm[{x10 , y10, z10} - {x20 , y20, z20}];
Timing[Do [
    ic = {x1[0] == x10, y1[0] == y10, z1[0] == z10, 
          x2[0] == x20, y2[0] == y20, z2[0] == z20};
    newstate = First@NDSolve`Reinitialize[state, ic];
    NDSolve`Iterate[newstate, dt];
    sol = Last /@ NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[newstate]; 
    d1 = Norm[sol[[1 ;; 3]] - sol[[4 ;; 6]]]; 
    sum += Log[d1/d0]; 
    lyap = sum/(dt*i); 
    lexp[[i]] = {dt*i, Log10[lyap]}; 
    {x10 , y10, z10} = sol[[1 ;; 3]]; 
    {x20 , y20, z20} = {x10 , y10, z10} + (sol[[1 ;; 3]] - sol[[4 ;; 6]]) (d0/d1); 
    If[Mod[dt*i, 10] == 0, Print["  t = ", dt*i, " , ", "largest Lyapunov  = ", lyap]], 
{i, iterat - 1}]]
```

Run time now is only 34 seconds.  This large additional savings results from moving `` NDSolve`ProcessEquations `` out of the loop

Comment: Thank you so much bbgodfrey, this completely solves my problem and is most illuminating .