# Computing the Lyuponov exponent for the Duffing system

Tags: differential-equations, code-request

Does anyone know (simple) Mathematica code for computing the Lyuponov exponent for the Duffing system?

```
x''[t] + 0.15 x'[t] - x[t] + x[t]^3== 7*Cos[t]
{x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}
```

Comment: The system is in chaotic state but I got negative values for  Lyapunov Exponents by using the suggested methods I am not sure what is wrong

Comment: Do you know what the right answer is?

Comment: No but at least one of them must be positive

Comment: P.S., welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice and your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My previous code for `LyapunovExponents` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179470/6358) did not handle non-autonomous systems like this properly.  Thanks for pointing that out!  I've updated it to fix this mistake and it seems to work now.

Putting your system in first-order form:

```
eqns = {x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -0.15 y[t] + x[t] - x[t]^3 + 7 Cos[t]};
```

Then calculating Lyapunov exponents:

```
LyapunovExponents[eqns, {x -> 0, y -> 0}, ShowPlot -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(* {0.10542, -0.25542} *)
```

Comment: I used your code after your modification and I was able to get very close results for this work
 https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0303077.pdf
for this eq: 
eqns = {x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == 2.5*Sin[t] - 0.1 y[t] - Sin[x[t]]};
 This is what I got 
{0.160632, -0.260632}
And this what they got
{0.160 , −0.262}
That is very good
By the way, should I always use the initial conditions for 
LyapunovExponents[eqns, {x -> 0, y -> 0}, ShowPlot -> True]

or the value for x and y at any time is fine?
Thanks you

Comment: Great, thanks for the link.  You can use whatever initial conditions (`t=0`) you want.