# Lyapunov exponent of Van der Pol-duffing oscillator by varying parametric forcing

Tags: differential-equations, code-request

For a parametric Van der Pol oscillator as given

```
x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -0.1*y[t]*(1 + f*Cos[1.0*t])*((x[t])^2 - 1) - 0.41*(x[t])^3 + (0.5^2)*x[t]
```

[image: LE=0.0515492, -0.0776195]

for `f=6.88`, the oscillator gives positive Lyapunov as following the method given in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/185466/66794, which shows the LE with respect to the time steps I have chosen. But I want a plot by varying `f` from `6.8 to 6.9`. I can't understand how to create the loop `f` from the code. Please help.

Comment: Do you want separate plots? In that case, you can use [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html): `Table[LyapunovExponents[eqns, ics, ShowPlot -> True], {f, 6.8, 6.9, 0.02}]` Or do you want all graphs shown in one plot?

Comment: No, I want a single plot of the `Lyapunov exponent` as a function of `f` instead of `steps`. @Domen

Answer (score 1):

Using `LyapunovExponents` from [@Chris K's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17593/lyapunov-exponent/179470#179470).

```
eqns = {x'[t] == y[t], 
   y'[t] == -0.1*y[t]*(1 + f*Cos[1.0*t])*((x[t])^2 - 1) - 
     0.41*(x[t])^3 + (0.5^2)*x[t]};
ics = {x -> 0, y -> 0};
exps = Transpose@
  ParallelTable[
   Transpose@{{f, f}, LyapunovExponents[eqns, ics]}, {f, 6.8, 
    6.9, .01}]
```

> `{{{6.8, 0.580633}, {6.81, 0.580715}, {6.82, 0.580797}, {6.83, 0.58088}, {6.84, 0.580962}, {6.85, 0.581044}, {6.86, 0.581127}, {6.87, 0.581209}, {6.88, 0.581292}, {6.89, 0.581375}, {6.9, 0.581458}}, {{6.8, -0.480654}, {6.81, -0.480736}, {6.82, -0.480818}, {6.83, -0.4809}, {6.84, -0.480983}, {6.85, -0.481065}, {6.86, -0.481148}, {6.87, -0.48123}, {6.88, -0.481313}, {6.89, -0.481396}, {6.9, -0.481479}}}`

```
ListPlot[exps, Joined -> True]
ListPlot[First@exps, Joined -> True]
```

[image: ListPlot]
[image: ListPlot]

Comment: Thank you so much! @Domen