# Lyapunov Exponent question about LCE package

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, dynamic, nonlinear

This code gives result as given below on my computer

```
Needs["LCE`"]; (*or*) Needs["lce`"];

F[{x_, y_, z_}] := {16 (y - x), x (45.92 - z) - y, x y - 4 z};
LCEsC[F, {19, 20, 50}, 0.1, 800, 20, 0.02]
LCEsC[F, {19, 20, 50}, 0.1, 800, 20, 0.02, LCEsPlot -> True]
```

> {{1.50085, 0.00327127, -22.4872}, 2.06689}

[image]

**However, it should have been as shown below as mentioned in the tutorial.**

[image]

How can I edit it? **PLEASE GUIDE ME**

Comment: Try this `Show[ LCEsC[F, {19, 20, 50}, 0.1, 800, 20, 0.02, LCEsPlot -> True], PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @LouisB or the author of the OP: out of curiosity, is this `LCE` package, the one written for the [Sandri methods](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7109/) or another one?

Comment: @kcr I used the Sandri package for Mathematica > 7 downloaded 2022-03-11 from [www.msandri.it/soft.html](https://www.msandri.it/soft.html) to duplicate the results in the OP.

Comment: @LouisB thanks a lot!

Comment: FYI, I updated this Sandri's code [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179470/6358) to use `NDSolve` instead of Euler method.  It should be faster / more accurate.