# Convergence plot of Lyapunov exponents

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, physics, nonlinear

I am trying to reproduce the convergence plot of the four Lyapunov exponents for a string from [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.09441.pdf) paper (page 12, figure 7).

The code that I have used till now to find the equations is given below:

```
K1 = 6.90; K2 = 16.05; K3 = 9.65; K4 = 3.27; K5 = 6.55;
\[Omega]sq[0] = -0.923; \[Omega]sq[1] = 6.478;
lagrangian = 
  Sum[c[n]'[t]^2 - c[n][t]^2 \[Omega]sq[n], {n, {0, 1}}] + 
   K1 c[0][t]^3 + K2 c[0][t] c[1][t]^2 + K3 c[0][t] c[0]'[t]^2 + 
   K4 c[0][t] c[1]'[t]^2 + K5 c[0]'[t] c[1][t] c[1]'[t];
c[0][t_] := OverTilde[c][0][t] + \[Alpha]1*OverTilde[c][0][t]^2 + \[Alpha]2*OverTilde[c][1][t]^2; 
c[1][t_] := OverTilde[c][1][t] + \[Alpha]3*OverTilde[c][0][t]*OverTilde[c][1][t]; 
\[Alpha]1 = -2; \[Alpha]2 = -0.5; \[Alpha]3 = -1;
n = Expand[lagrangian];
vars = {OverTilde[c][0][t], OverTilde[c][1][t], 
   Derivative[1][OverTilde[c][0]][t], 
       Derivative[1][OverTilde[c][1]][t]};
lagrangian = 
  Normal[Series[n /. Thread[vars -> m*vars], {m, 0, 3}]] /. m -> 1;
momentum[n_] := D[lagrangian, Derivative[1][OverTilde[c][n]][t]]
hamiltonian = Expand[Sum[momentum[n]*Derivative[1][OverTilde[c][n]][t], {n, {0, 1}}] - lagrangian]; 
eulerLagrange[lagrangian_, vars_, dvars_] := 
       Thread[Table[D[D[lagrangian, dvar], t], {dvar, dvars}] - Table[D[lagrangian, var], {var, vars}] == 
         ConstantArray[0, Length[vars]]]; 
    equationsOfMotion = eulerLagrange[lagrangian, {OverTilde[c][0][t], OverTilde[c][1][t]}, 
        {Derivative[1][OverTilde[c][0]][t], Derivative[1][OverTilde[c][1]][t]}]
```

Comment: If you can convert your second-order system to a system of first-order equations, you could use the LyapunovExponents function [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179470/6358).  I tried, but couldn't even get the system to `NDSolve` on  it own, due to stiffness.  Did you manage to numerically solve your system?  What are the initial conditions?

Comment: @ChrisK, at first I tried solving my system with Marco Sandri's package for Lyapunov Exponents, but the code kept on running indefinitely without any output. When I tried your function, after converting my system to a first-order one, I am getting lots of errors and warning messages. The initial conditions for the problem are specified in figure 7 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.09441.pdf (on page 12)

Comment: Can you get even `NDSolve` to work on the model?  Before calculating the Lyapunov exponents, you should be able to solve the dynamics.

Comment: Actually, I used the above equations to plot a Poincare section using NDSolve and WhenEvent, hence I assumed it to be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I uncovered an unexpected little bug in `LyapunovExponents` that caused those errors.  If you use the updated version from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17593/lyapunov-exponent/179470#179470), it now seems to work.

Wrangle into first-order form:

```
eqns = Flatten@Join[
   Solve[
      equationsOfMotion, {Derivative[2][OverTilde[c][0]][t], 
       Derivative[2][OverTilde[c][1]][t]}] /. {
      Derivative[2][OverTilde[c][0]][t] -> Derivative[1][dc[0]][t], 
      Derivative[2][OverTilde[c][1]][t] -> Derivative[1][dc[1]][t],
      Derivative[1][OverTilde[c][0]][t] -> dc[0][t], 
      Derivative[1][OverTilde[c][1]][t] -> dc[1][t]} /. (lhs_ -> 
       rhs_) -> (lhs == rhs),
   {OverTilde[c][0]'[t] == dc[0][t], OverTilde[c][1]'[t] == dc[1][t]}];
```

Warm up system to get good ICs for LyapunovExponents (note: I guessed `dc[1][0]==0` since the paper didn't give it explicitly):

```
tmax = 100;
sol = NDSolve[{eqns, {OverTilde[c][0][0] == -0.0002, 
      OverTilde[c][1][0] == 0.0011, dc[0][0] == 0, 
      dc[1][0] == 0}}, {OverTilde[c][0], OverTilde[c][1], dc[0], 
     dc[1]}, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];
Plot[Evaluate[{OverTilde[c][0][t], OverTilde[c][1][t], dc[0][t], 
    dc[1][t]} /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All]
ics = {OverTilde[c][0] -> (OverTilde[c][0][tmax] /. sol), 
  OverTilde[c][1] -> (OverTilde[c][1][tmax] /. sol), 
  dc[0] -> (dc[0][tmax] /. sol), dc[1] -> (dc[1][tmax] /. sol)};
```

[image]

Calculate the exponents:

```
LyapunovExponents[eqns, ics, ShowPlot -> True, PlotExponents -> 4, 
 PlotOpts -> {AxesLabel -> {"step", "\[Lambda]"}, 
   PlotRange -> {-0.006, 0.006}, GridLines -> Automatic}, 
 MaxSteps -> 2 10^4]
(* {0.00158325, 3.17326*10^-6, -0.00026645, -0.00130408} *)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed answer! I am getting the first plot but I am not sure why I am still getting errors and warning messages for the Lyapunov Exponents: https://imgur.com/a/h9YWPag . The code is still running and I am not able to get the main plot.

Comment: I also got this error for different initial conditions.  Do you use the same parameters / ICs as in my answer?  In any case, it's because the system is stiff and once it fails, it's a lost cause.  You could try adding `NDSolveOpts -> {AccuracyGoal -> 16}` to see if that helps, or play with other `NDSolve` options.

Comment: I have used the same parameters as in your answer. I will try to use other `NDSolve` options and let you know if I get similar results.

Comment: OK! My `$Version` is `13.0.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)`, which might account for the different outcome.

Comment: I am using Mathematica 11 for Windows 10 (64-bit). The system is running the code after I made minor modifications. It is taking a much longer time than expected. Hopefully, it works.

Comment: I was finally able to get the Lyapunov Convergence plot after playing around a lot with `NDSolveOpts`. Thank you so much for the code :) I just have one final doubt. How do I plot the sum of Lyapunov Exponents? Do I need to extract the data from the above plot and form a table to calculate the sum or some other algorithm needs to be used?

Comment: The easiest would be to add to `LyapunovExponents` at the end, by the other `ListPlot` command, something like `Print[ListPlot[Total[Transpose[edat]],  Evaluate[Sequence @@ plotopts]]]`.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. How to change the step size? Shall I use TStep -> 0.001 for a step size of 0.001?

Comment: @codebpr The `TStep` option is how long to run `NDSolve` between renormalizations, not the time step within `NDSolve` (to change that, use `NDSolveOpts -> {MaxStepSize -> 0.001}`).   So `TStep -> 0.001` might be excessively small (depending on the time scale of your system of course).

Comment: Thank you for the help. Just one last question. I am writing a paper with Lyapunov exponents as one of the key features and I want to cite your algorithm. I am not sure how to cite it from stackexchange. Do you have any paper with your algorithm which I can cite?

Comment: @codebpr Great! It's not really my algorithm though. I first learned about it from Wolf et al. (1985) Section 3 and Appendix A, and my implementation is an extension of Sandri (1996).  I added these references to [https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17593/lyapunov-exponent/179470#179470].

Comment: Thank you! I am facing certain issues while using a smaller step size . The code runs for hours on my pc and I couldn't afford to lose this amount of time. Sometimes the system freezes due to ram deficiency and power cut. This could have been avoided if I could write the data into a data file for each step. So, could you please help me edit your code such that I can export the numerical results into a data file in order to compare my graphs at later times without worrying about waiting for too long or other accidents?

Comment: @codebpr Sorry I don't have time to do that. You could post your problem as a separate question and maybe someone can help you, either by changing settings or writing data to disk as you suggest.