# 0-1 test or Lyapunov exponent, to prove my below system is chaotic?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, nonlinear, code-request

The following question is a part of my research [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/282645/66737),I want to calulate the Lyaponov exponents of the following dynamics to show  whether i have a chaotic dynamics or not.  $$
\ddot{x}-ax+bx^{3}+cx^{5}+A \,\cos \left(( \omega t)\right)+\gamma\, \dot{x}=g,\dot x(0) =0,x(0)=0
$$
with
$$g: n \mapsto \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
         \left \lfloor{n/\sqrt{2}} \right \rfloor & \text{ if } n \text{ even,}  \\
         \left \lfloor{n\sqrt{2}} \right \rfloor & \text{ if } n \text{ odd.}
    \end{array}
\right.$$
I just took the case of n is odd .
Here is my Code :

```
Clear[A];
solution[A_, tmax_] := 
 NDSolve[{v'[t] == 
    x[t] - x[t]^3 - 0.05*v[t] + A*Cos[1.1*t] - 
     FractionalPart[2024/Sqrt[2]], x'[t] == v[t], x[0] == 0, 
   v[0] == 0}, {x, v}, {t, 0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> 100*tmax]
sol3 = solution[0.2, 800]
graph[tmin_, tmax_] := 
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], v[t]} /. sol3], {t, tmin, tmax}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "v"}]
graph[0, 200]
sol3 = {x -> 0.5, v -> -1.34};
LyapunovExponents[sol3, ShowPlot -> True]
```

But I didn't get any values of Lyaponov exponents however i was able to show the parametric plot of my dynamics

Thanks for any help or any comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume you're using the `LyapunovExponents` function I wrote [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179470/6358).  The first step is to make sure you're starting on the attractor. In your case, it seems that after some complicated transient dynamics, the system ends on a simple (non-chaotic) limit cycle.

```
A = 0.2;
tmax = 800;

sol = NDSolve[{
  v'[t] == x[t] - x[t]^3 - 0.05*v[t] + A*Cos[1.1*t] - FractionalPart[2024/Sqrt[2]],
  x'[t] == v[t], x[0] == 0, v[0] == 0}, {x, v}, {t, 0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> 100*tmax][[1]];

Plot[{x[t], v[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, tmax}]
ParametricPlot[{x[t], v[t]} /. sol, {t, tmax - 100, tmax}]
{x[tmax], v[tmax]} /. sol
(* {-0.927737, -0.0327212} *)
```

[image]

[image]

We can verify with `LyapunovExponents` like this:

```
LyapunovExponents[{
  v'[t] == x[t] - x[t]^3 - 0.05*v[t] + A*Cos[1.1*t] - FractionalPart[2024/Sqrt[2]], 
  x'[t] == v[t]}, {x -> -0.9277372619912159`, v -> -0.032721216898167094`}, ShowPlot -> True]
```

[image]

```
{-0.0249872, -0.0250129}
```

Both exponents are negative, indicating non-chaotic dynamics.

I noticed that your code is missing the `- x[t]^5` term in the equations you wrote.  Maybe including that would help find chaos (but based on my quick exploration, be sure to increase `tmax` because there maybe be loooonnnng transients).