# Indeterminate Lyapunov exponenet for four-wing attractor

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, code-review

We are using  [Chris K](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/6358/chris-k)'s [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179470/84456) on [another question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17593/84456) for finding Lyapunov Exponents for a dynamical system (Four-Wing Attractor)

```
GramSchmidt[w_?MatrixQ] := Module[{v = ConstantArray[0, Length[w]]}, 
  Table[v[[n]] = w[[n]] - Sum[(v[[i]].w[[n]]/v[[i]].v[[i]])*v[[i]], {i, n - 1}], {n, Length[w]}]; v]

LyapunovExponents[eqnsin_List, icsin : ({__Rule} | _Association), nlein_Integer: 0, opts___?OptionQ] := Module[{

(* options *)
tstep, maxsteps, ndsolveopts, logbase, showplot, plotexponents, plotopts,

(* iterators *)
c, i, j,

(* other variables *)
δ, neq, nle, vars, rhs, jac, eqns, unks, ics, cum, res, edat, state, newstate, sol, W, norms},
   
(* parse options *)
tstep = Evaluate[TStep /. Flatten[{opts, Options[LyapunovExponents]}]];
maxsteps = Evaluate[MaxSteps /. Flatten[{opts, Options[LyapunovExponents]}]];
ndsolveopts = Evaluate[NDSolveOpts /. Flatten[{opts, Options[LyapunovExponents]}]];
logbase =Evaluate[LogBase /. Flatten[{opts, Options[LyapunovExponents]}]];
showplot = Evaluate[ShowPlot /. Flatten[{opts, Options[LyapunovExponents]}]];
plotexponents = Evaluate[PlotExponents /. Flatten[{opts, Options[LyapunovExponents]}]];
plotopts = Evaluate[PlotOpts /. Flatten[{opts, Options[LyapunovExponents]}]];
  
neq = Length[eqnsin];
If[nlein == 0, nle = neq, nle = nlein]; (* how many exponents *)
   
(* extract vars and right hand sides from eqnsin *)
vars = eqnsin[[All, 1, 0, 1]];
rhs = eqnsin[[All, 2]];
   
(* jacobian matrix *)
jac = D[rhs, {Replace[vars, {x_ -> x[t]}, 1]}];
   
eqns = Join[
  eqnsin,
  Flatten[Table[δ[i, j]'[t] == (jac.Table[δ[i, j][t], {i, neq}])[[i]], {j, nle}, {i, neq}]]
];
unks = Join[
  vars,
  Flatten[Table[δ[i, j], {j, nle}, {i, neq}]]
];
ics = Join[
  Table[var[0] == (var /. icsin), {var, vars}],
  Flatten[Table[δ[i, j][0] == IdentityMatrix[neq][[i, j]], {j, nle}, {i, neq}]]
];

cum = Table[0, {nle}];

state = First@NDSolve`ProcessEquations[Flatten[Join[eqns, ics]], unks, t, Evaluate[Sequence @@ ndsolveopts]];

(* main loop *) 

edat = Table[
  newstate = First@NDSolve`Reinitialize[state, ics];
  NDSolve`Iterate[newstate, c tstep];
  sol = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[newstate];

  W = GramSchmidt[Evaluate[Table[δ[i, j][c tstep], {j, nle}, {i, neq}] /. sol]];
  norms = Map[Norm, W];

  (* update running vector magnitudes *)
  cum = cum + Log[logbase, norms];

  ics = Join[
    Table[var[c tstep] == (var[c tstep] /. sol), {var, vars}],
    Flatten[Table[δ[i, j][c tstep] == (W/norms)[[j, i]], {j, nle}, {i, neq}]]
  ];
  cum/(c tstep)
, {c, maxsteps}];
   
If[showplot, Print[ListPlot[Transpose[edat][[1 ;; plotexponents]], Evaluate[Sequence @@ plotopts]]]];
   
Return[cum/(maxsteps tstep)]
];

Options[LyapunovExponents] = {NDSolveOpts -> {}, TStep -> 1, MaxSteps -> 10^4, LogBase -> E,
  ShowPlot -> False, PlotExponents -> 1, PlotOpts -> {}};
```

Our initial conditions and the equations are given below.

```
ics = {x -> 0.1, y -> 0.1, z -> 0.1};

equations= {Derivative[1][x][t] == 14 (-x[t] + y[t]) + 4 y[t] z[t], 
 Derivative[1][z][t] == x[t] y[t] - 43 z[t], 
 Derivative[1][y][t] == 8.1 x[t] + 16 y[t] - x[t] z[t]}


LyapunovExponents[equations, ics]
    {0.000634328, -3.35805, Indeterminate}
```

> However, one of the results is **Indeterminate** and we are clueless
> about the cause.

Is there a problem in the code, or does the system genuinely an indeterminate Lyapunov exponent?

Please help us resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's neither an indeterminate Lyapunov exponent nor a problem with the code, just it needs a bit more careful application.  The first thing to do is to simulate the model, to get an idea of what's happening and to get good initial conditions for `LyapunovExponents`.

```
sol = NDSolve[{equations, {x[0] == 0.1, y[0] == 0.1, z[0] == 0.1}},
  {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 1000}][[1]];
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol], {t, 990, 1000}]
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol], {t, 990, 1000}]
```

[image]

[image]

Based on this, I think your system reaches a limit cycle, not a chaotic attractor.  Therefore the Lyapunov exponents should be 0 (phase shift on the cycle) and two negative numbers (showing attraction to the limit cycle).

Using the final values of `sol` as initial conditions for `LyapunovExponents` helps it converge faster, which you can see with the `ShowPlot` option.

```
LyapunovExponents[equations, ics, ShowPlot -> True]
(* {0.000466946, -3.35772, Indeterminate} *)
```

[image]

versus

```
ics2 = Thread[{x, y, z} -> ({x[1000], y[1000], z[1000]} /. sol)]
LyapunovExponents[equations, ics2, ShowPlot -> True]
(* {-0.0000533646, -3.35716, Indeterminate} *)
```

[image]

Notice how the first exponent got an order of magnitude closer to `0` by starting on the attractor?

Finally, about those `Indeterminate` values.  The algorithm has to re-orthonormalize the solution to the variational equation `δ` periodically because the dominant exponent, well, dominates the others.  You can read more about it in [Wolf et al. 1985](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0167278985900119) and [Sandri 1996](https://venturi.soe.ucsc.edu/sites/default/files/Numerical_Calculation_of_Lyapunov_Exponents.pdf), which were the basis of `LyapunovExponents`.  The default value for this `TStep` is 1, which is too large for your system, which oscillates fairly rapidly.  Reducing `TStep` (and increasing `MaxSteps` from its default of `10^4` accordingly) fixes that problem:

```
LyapunovExponents[equations, ics2, ShowPlot -> True, TStep -> 0.1, MaxSteps -> 10^5]
{-0.0000531121, -3.35716, -37.6428}
```

[image]

That `-37.6428` is the problem child. If you want to doublecheck, decrease `TStep` again and put the kettle on (this takes like 5 minutes):

```
LyapunovExponents[equations, ics2, TStep -> 0.001, MaxSteps -> 10^6]
(* {0.000490278, -3.35846, -37.642} *)
```

Pretty similar.

If you want more accuracy in your exponents, increase `MaxSteps` further.  If you only care about the dominant exponent, you can ask for only one exponent and get away with the default (or even larger) `TStep`:

```
LyapunovExponents[equations, ics, 1]
(* {0.000466672} *)
```

Even better, since the solution is periodic, you could calculate the equivalent [Floquet exponents](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12080-008-0016-2) instead, which only needs integration over one period.  Unfortunately I don't have code for this implemented in base Mathematica, but using my [EcoEvo package](https://github.com/cklausme/ecoevo) I get:

```
(* {-2.32332*10^-7, -3.35701, -37.643} *)
```

which lines up well.