# Bibtex like citation request in MMA stack exchange

Tags: reference-request, resourcefunction

I have been using the **ResourceFunction["ClickPoincarePlot2D"]** developed by @[E. Chan-López](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/53427/e-chan-l%C3%B3pez) and the [Lyapunov exponent algorithm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179470/78049) developed by @[Chris K](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/6358/chris-k) in many of my works. It would be very beneficial to other users(particularly those working on non-linear dynamics) and me on this MMA StackExchange if we could cite important algorithms in our research work to give due credit to the authors. Usually, in academic stack sites, there is a `cite` button like in [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com) and [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com).

If possible, can't there also be a similar feature here in the Mathematica StackExchange?

Or maybe some other temporary solution to get a BibTeX citation?

**Note:** This question has also been asked in [meta](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2766/78049). I hope admins and moderators consider it, as some of the answers here carry a lot of effort and would be worthy of getting a citation since sometimes they serve a bigger purpose.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Functions in the WFR are published under the [CC BY 4.0 Deed](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/), as indicated at the bottom of the page. When sharing, you have to attribute the author, provide the link, and indicate any changes.

Comment: @Domen, sorry but I had to ask it again here as  I saw no response [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2766/78049) on meta.

Comment: But what are you expecting us to do? Obviously, we can't implement this button, so you should send this request to the WRI :) Until then, just cite it as you would cite any other software.

Comment: As I understand the question is about `cite` button which exists under every topic for example on   https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions. Why not to have it on this forum? Moderator and Admin can solve this problem in one click.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, ah, alright, sure. Still, this request then belongs to Meta, not here. codebpr, you've posted the question 11 h ago; give it some time :)

Comment: @Domen Post here is more visibly than that on meta. :)

Comment: This might be out of scope for MSE but I upvoted because making algorithm and software citation easier would be a good thing. And this post draws attention to the general issue.